# How to hide hdri background?

Tags: hdri

I have added an hdri environment file and i want to use the lights and not the background image. Is there any option present to hide the image and just use the light source.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image]

In the properties panel, World section, Ray Visibility tab, unceck the "Camera" option.

Comment: perfect and thanks 1 one additional question i can c the black background can we change the color from back to some other color

Comment: If you have additional question open up a new question. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 33):

In `Blender 2.8x`, this can be done by ticking the `Transparent` checkbox in `Render Properties`:

Properties Panel > Render > Film > [x] Transparent

[image: Blender 2.8 Transparent Background]

Comment: Is there a way to make it so you can replace the background with a different background that you want?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamer In this case I'd use a simple plane with a color or a texture, facing the camera directly.

Answer (score 11):

I usually just use this node setup for the environment to hide the HDRI from the camera. It also allows for some flexibility if one were to want the visible background to be say, blue or have a gradient and light the scene with the HDRI instead of turning off camera rays altogether.

---

The [light path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html#light-path-node) *is camera ray* output as mixing factor makes the camera see the black [background shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/background.html#background), while the environment receives the lighting from the HDRI.

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: THIS! I have been searching for this for years..... thank you!