# How to use a 2D video to make a skybox and reflect it in a mirror object

Tags: mirror, reflection, skybox

I have a 2D video (nothing special, just view from ground) of a sky with clouds passing by. I want to use it and have it reflected on the surface of a complicated curved mirror-like 3D object in my scene. I think that what I want is called a skybox but my "texture" is a normal video, not a panoramic video.

The reflection doesn't have to be precise. My object could even be "satin finished" instead of mirror so it's more about "atmosphere" than precision. I want the viewer of the final render to feel that the object was there, surrounded by this cloud sky.

Just point me to a tutorial fs you know one. I will learn from there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Staddy camera or in motion? Please add some screenshots of your video ... view angle matters ... also how environment in video looks like ... what is the motion of camera ... Here is one way for still image https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140477/2214

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The video footage itself was filmed from a fixed camera. It is very similar to this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssRFnkZBdUY . The Blender camera looking at my object is also steady but my object is rotating around z (vertical) axis. So imagine a mirrored default cube or sphere rotating on itself and reflecting on its faces the footage of passing clouds video. I will study the example in the link provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another similar option that make less distortion on mirror (metallic), but some edges on glass ... For *World shader* is used video texture in E*nvironmental node >* **Mirror Ball** ... plus video object behind.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @vklidu! That's exactly what I did finally :) I also wanted to remove the background for later compositing so I used this method: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65137/how-to-hide-hdri-background) which worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

One dirty way ... World Shader with video texture mapped as type *Window* for Camera view mixed with the same video texture mapped as type *Generated* to stretch texture arround for ambient ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Like now texture is the same behind the camera (is repeated) it doesn't look natural of course, but probably not an issue in your case. Your camera is pointed to clouds so ... in reality object should reflect ground, but I would say you want to reflect clouds as well, so this could work for you.

---

You can probably "fix" reflection if you use instead of World shader another object as Dome (big Sphere) unwrapped and for back part behind camera combine with some gradient to make darken opposite side.

Comment: Thank you very much vklidu! I think you suggestion will do it. I'm going to try now and report back with results. Thanks again for your time and effort!